# How to add values to System.Object Variable inside a foreach loop container with script task in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, script-task, foreach-loop-container

I'm trying to add new values to a variable (System.Object) inside a foreach loop container that is using that variable. How can i do that ?

To understand my flow :

[image]

first script i'm adding a value to that variable and its working fine.

[image]

But inside the loop when i'm trying to add new values to that variable its not working :(

I've tried this 2 codes:

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("LISTA_CONTACTOS");
myDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("columnText", typeof(string)));
DataRow myDataRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
myDataRow["columnText"] = "1";
myDataTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);
Dts.Variables["User::LISTA_CONTACTOS"].Value = myDataTable;
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)Dts.Variables["LISTA_CONTACTOS"].Value;
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("contact_id", typeof(string)));
DataRow newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
newRow["contact_id"] = "8535939";
dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
Dts.Variables["LISTA_CONTACTOS"].Value = dataTable;
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Think its something like that ...

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Is `LISTA_CONTACTOS` set as read only or a read-write variable? What variable is for the Foreach Loop Container enumerating over?

Answer (score 0):

I've just achieved this. I did the following:

Initialize your new `DataTable` *outside* of your ForLoop and assign it to the variable. The following steps are:

1. Create a new Script task *outside* of the ForLoop:
   [image]
2. Ensure that the SSIS variable you've created has ReadWite access in the script:
   [image]
3. Inside the Script, initialize your new `DataTable`. Add the columns you need. Then set your SSIS variable to the `DataTable` variable:

   ```
   public voide Main()
   {
       DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

       tbl.Columns.Add("ID");
       tbl.Columns.Add("Column1");
       tbl.Columns.Add("Column2");
       tbl.Columns.Add("Column3");

       tbl.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { tbl.Columns["ID"] };

       Dts.Variables["User::AllRecordsTable"].Value = tbl;

       Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
   }
   ```
4. Inside your ForLoop, create a new Script. Ensure that the variable has ReadWrite access (like in step 2). In the code, you can then append rows onto your data table:

   ```
   public override void PostExecute()
   {
       var recordDataTable = (DataTable) Variables.AllRecordsTable;
       var rowCount = recordDataTable.Rows.Count;

       recordDataTable.Rows.Add(
           rowCount + 1,
           "ColumnValue1",
           "ColumnValue2",
           "ColumnValue3",
       );
   }
   ```

FYI: In step 3, I used a `Script Task` inside the `Control Flow`. In step 4, I used a `Script Component` inside a `Data Flow`. That explains the difference in function names and the way we access SSIS variables.